# JNI with android?

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, android-ndk

Hey guys!
I've been working on c++ application lately which has to be run on Android 2.1 and 2.2. 
so I am wondering if I have complete c++ application can I just put it into *.so file and then create android project and just simply load this library using System.loadLibrary(blalba.so);
would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will have to recompile all the native libraries specifically for Android. Yes, you do need the source code for all 3rd party native libs you plan to use simply because Usually when we compile and link these libraries outside Android they are linked to glibc but unfortunately Android doesn't use glibc due to liscence and performance issues. Android uses a watered down version of glibc called ***libc***. It has matching symbol names to glibc for most of the usual functionalities. But as far as i know the libc doesn't have some functionality related to Strings and it definitely doesnt have some posix support. If your native libraries are using any of the deprecated functionality you will have to find workaround for those by using alternative functionality supported by libc and coding your libs accordingly.

Also, as you righty pointed out you will have to use the NDK to interface Java(Android app/fwk) to native world(C++).

Though this sounds pretty simple in my experience compiling native libraries on Android(Android porting) has traditionally been very time consuming with no guarantee of sucesses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment, it is really helpful. By the way, is there are some specific in coding for Android, specially for 2.1 and 2.2 or it could be just regular C++ and java code?

Comment: @user747228: Android has a 3 layered architecture, where the lower most layer is native(C/C++), a Jni Layer(called App Fwk) sits on top of it and Java based applications sit on top of the App Fwk. The C, C++ code gets linked against Android libc so it must be compliant to it(details of what I remember is different is in answer). About, App Fwk and App, they use the functionality exposed by the Android SDK, which is more or less core java but Android refuses to say it Java though.

Comment: @user747228: If you do find the answer and comment useful, don't forget to mark them as accepted answer :)

Comment: To add to the above you will also have to compile for each platform you wish to support, package all .so's and load the appropriate one at runtime. This hasn't been an issue when Android was essentially ARM-only. These days, however, there are Intel-based devices out in the wild (and possibly others).